# Unable to set datefield value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form with several fields. One of those fields has xtype of datefield. Values for this form come from a json file, which looks like so:

```
{"field_1":"text value", "field_2": "2017-08-16T21:00:00.000Z"}
```

However, when I do:

```
form.setValues(json);
```

only the first field is set. The second datefield, which is defined like:

```
{
    "xtype":"datefield",
    "name": "field_2"
}
```

is not set for some reason. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JSON does not support javascript dates natively, the value in field_2 is a string, not a javascript date.

While a string can represent a date, there are a variety of formats. In this case the string is in a format unrecognized by datefield. When the datefield tries to set the value, it will try to parse the string into a date, but since your selected  format is not one known to datefield by default, the value is set to null.

The [`format`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-format) and [`altFormats`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-altFormats) configs contain the formats datefield recognizes, and can be exchanged/amended to contain the date format(s) you want to support.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to set `"format": "d.m.Y", "dateFormat":"Y-m-dTH:i:s.uZ"`,but it did not help. Don't you know what is wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Great! Thank you, sir!